# DD command: Create an partition image without save filesystem

Tags: shell, filesystems, dd, disk-image

I have the initial situation:

[image]

I have executed the commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/part1.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sda2 of=~/part2.img
```

After this, i have prepared the new partitions for restoring the images:

[image]

After this, i have resored the images:

```
sudo dd if=~/part1.img of=/dev/sda1
sudo dd if=~/part2.img of=/dev/sda2
```

With this result:

[image]

How can I create an partition image without save filesystem?

Comment: I hope you're not using `dd` to take images of partitions that contain mounted filesystems unless you want the duplicated filesystems to be corrupt.

Comment: As I see: is it the goal to enlarge the "rootfs"? If yes, there is a *resize* function in Gparted. BTW the filesystem is fixed in the saved dd image of partition /dev/sda2 and you cannot change it just only by relabeling the new disk partition